# Matrix inequality involving product to two positive definite matrices $(AA^T)(BB^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$
where $m > n > p$ and $A, B$ are full rank.

For $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|x\|_2=1$, let us consider
$$
f(x) = x^T(A^TA)(BB^T)x.
$$
Can we conclude that 
$$
f(x) \ge \sigma^2_{\min}(A^TABB^T)\|x\|^2 ? \quad \text{or} \quad 
\ge \sigma_{\min}^2(A)\sigma_{\min}^2(B)\|x\|^2 ?
$$
or a lower bound which involves singular values of $A$ or $B$?
Here, for a matrix $M$ of size $s \times k$, 
$\sigma_{\min}(M)$ is the $\min\{s,k\}$-th largest singular value of $M$.

Here is my attempt. 
Since $BB^T$ is symmetric positive definite, we can write it as 
$BB^T = R^{1/2}R^{1/2}$ where $R^{1/2}$ is a $p \times p$ symmeric matrix.
Since $R^{1/2}A^TAR^{1/2}$ is symmetric, it is diagonalizable. Thus we have
$$
A^TABB^T = R^{-1/2}(R^{1/2}A^TAR^{1/2})R^{1/2} = R^{-1/2}(Q\Sigma Q)R^{1/2},
$$
and 
$$
f(x) = x^TA^TABB^Tx = (x^TR^{-1/2}Q)\Sigma (QR^{1/2}x).
$$
If $R^{-1/2} = (R^{1/2})^T$, $BB^T = I$ and the statement is obvious.
If $R^{-1/2} \ne (R^{1/2})^T$, I am not sure what would be a valid lower bound in terms of singular values of $A$ or $B$.

Any suggestions/comments/answers will be very appreciated.

Comment: Given any nonsingular $B$, we can easily arrange $ABB'x=0$ from the "more freedom" of $A$ coming from $m> p$. So let us take $B$ with one identity $p\times p$ block near a zero block, so that $BB'=I$, fix some $x$, take $A$ with $Ax=0$. If i correctly understand, we take $\sigma_{\text{min}}(A)$ to be largest under the $p\times p$ minors of $A$...

Comment: @dan_fulea I am sorry. I don't get what your point is. If $BB^T = I$, what we have is just $x^TA^TAx = \|Ax\|^2$. Thus, $f(x) \ge \sigma_{\min}^2(A)\|x\|^2$. Here $\sigma_{\min}(A)$ is the $\min\{m,p\}$-th largest singular value...

Comment: It may be that i am missing something, but the setting above gives for that one specific $x\ne 0$ with $Ax=0$ the relation $f(x)=0$, but $\sigma^2_{\text{min}}(A)\|x\|^2>0$ for an $A$ with the symmetric semidefinite $A'A$ (a $p\times p$-matrix) with at least one eigenvalue $>0$. If i correctly understand, that minimum of $m$ and $p$ is $p$, we take the $p$ eigenvalues of $A'A$, sort them increasingly, $0\le \sigma_1(A)\le \sigma_2(A)\le\dots\le \sigma_p(A)$, take the biggest one, which is $\sigma_p(A)$.